# How to create a SHA256SUMS file?

Tags: hashing

I can check the content of several files in a directory against checksums contained in a file named for example SHA256SUMS with
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS.

1. Is there an easy way to generate a SHA256SUMS file for all files in a directory?
2. What is the exact syntax of the SHA256SUMS file and where is the documentation (if any) of that syntax?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Using Bash on Ubuntu. But I hope to get an answer that works on most linuxes.

Comment: Solved it now with: sha256sum -b * > SHA256SUMS. Part 2 of question is still open.

Comment: See my answer for your part 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but it worked for me:

```
cd directory
sha256sum -b * > SHA256SUMS
```

Don't know what it does if there are sub-directories in directory.
For documentation see DavidPostill's answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Where is the documentation for sha256sums?

The GNU Core Utils documentation for md5sum can be found at:

- [6.4 md5sum: Print or check MD5 digests](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#md5sum-invocation) and
- [6.6 sha2 utilities: Print or check SHA-2 digests](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sha2-utilities).

In addition:

> The full documentation for sha256sum is maintained as a
>   Texinfo manual. If `info` and `sha256sum` are properly installed at
>   your site, the command
>
> ```
> info coreutils 'sha256sum invocation'
> ```
>
> should give you access to the complete manual.

Source [sha256sum](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/sha256sum.1.html) — compute and check SHA256 message digest

Comment: I would have to learn how to use "info" first. But I found an easier to read online version, which points to the md5sum documentation at http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#md5sum-invocation.

Answer (score 0):

`sha256sum -b` does not work recursively

Do this: `find . -type f -exec sha256sum {} > checksums.txt \;`

-type -f is needed to exclude directories
, -exec rather than -execdir in order to get the path included in the checksums list, which facilitates automatic checking